# Flutter geolocation not showing anything

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, google-geolocation

I am new to flutter and trying to create a geolocation.
however, for my following code, the screen only shows 'Loading.. Please wait..' and the map is not showing.

i am just trying to show the current location using dependencies

> geolocator: ^6.1.1

Using the codes from

> https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#3

the Google map can be shown successfully. So it is not issues related to Google Maps Platform.

```
// home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool mapToggle = false;
  var currentLocation;
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
      });
    });
  }

  void _onMapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 80.0,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: mapToggle
                    ? GoogleMap(
                        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
                                currentLocation.longitude),
                            zoom: 10.0))
                    : Center(
                        child: Text(
                        'Loading.. Please wait..',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      )))
          ],
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified by printing the value of Current location in setState that you actually get the location value? The reason being you are not asking for permission to the user to access their location. I may be wrong but that would be a good starting point. Also, for location purpose, I generally use package called location, it lets you ask for user permission, maybe geolocate also has it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your AndroidManifest add permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

**initialize variable**

```
Position _currentPosition;
```

**Copy this function and call this in initState**

```
_getCurrentLocation() async{
   Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentPosition = position;
     
      });

    
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
  }
```

For more info checkout their pub.dev site [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/versions/6.1.1)under usage,make sure you setup correctly for android and ios

Comment: Thanks. Android Studio shows getCurrentPosition is deprecated. It should be Geolocator.getCurrentPosition

Comment: This code is used in my project 1 month ago,guess i need to update it too,if this help you please upvote the answer also i have updated answer too@eagle

Answer (score 2):

As @theredcap already pointed out in his comment, you most probably don't have the necessary permissions. Always read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/versions/6.1.1) of the plugin that you are using.

I don't see:

```
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
```

nor do I see:

```
LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
```

in your code at all, yet the plugin docs clearly explain that part. Also, in case you are new to Android in general, take a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: In geolocator you don't need to specify this,i have project that working with geolocator,but i have't specified any of this code,but it's request permission and also shows open location service dialog,after the 6 + update it's working very good@Uroš